# Multiplicative group modulo n isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, ring-theory

I know the statement of [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n#General_composite_numbers), but I don't remember seeing a proof for the part about the isomorphism of the group of units. So I would like to write a proof of this.

Consider an integer $n$ with prime factor decomposition $\prod_{i=1}^{l}{p_i}^{k_i}$. Then let

$$f:\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z\to\prod_{i=1}^{l}(\Bbb Z/{p_i}^{k_i} \Bbb Z)$$

be a ring isomorphism.

For existence of reciprocal, we need $f((\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^\times)\subseteq \prod_{i=1}^{l}((\Bbb Z/{p_i}^{k_i} \Bbb Z)^\times)$. Observe that the cardinality of $f((\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^\times)$ is $\phi(n)$ ($\phi$ is Euler totient function) as $f$ is injective, while $\prod_{i=1}^{l}((\Bbb Z/{p_i}^{k_i} \Bbb Z)^\times)$ also has cardinality $\phi(n)$ by multiplicativeness of $\phi$. Hence, $f((\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^\times)=\prod_{i=1}^{l}((\Bbb Z/{p_i}^{k_i} \Bbb Z)^\times)$. With proper restriction,

$$f:(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^\times\to \prod_{i=1}^{l}((\Bbb Z/{p_i}^{k_i} \Bbb Z)^\times)$$

is both a group homomorphism and bijective function, and hence the two groups of units are isomorphic.

Is there anything wrong with the above proof? And is there a more general way of proving this result, like whether we know the group of units of a direct product of rings with unity, i.e. do we have

$$(\prod_iR_i)^\times\cong\prod_i(R_i)^\times?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is valid if you're allowed to use the fact that $\phi$ is multiplicative. Personally, the Chinese Remainder Theorem is what I consider to be *the reason* that $\phi$ is multiplicative, so this would be circular for me.

Yes, we do have $(\prod_i R_i)^\times=\prod_i R_i^\times$. It is actually straightforward to prove they are equal as subsets of $\prod_i R_i$: show every element of the former is an element of the latter and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

**Remark**

I think that the multiplicativeness of $\phi$ should rather be considered as a *consequence* of the fact that the groups of units of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and $\displaystyle{\prod_{i=1}^j\left(\mathbb{Z}/p_i^{k_i}\mathbb{Z}\right)}$ are isomorphic and hence equipotent.

**Detail**

Let $u=A\to B$ a ring isomomorphism. For all $x\in A$, the inversibility of $x$ means the existence of $x'\in A$ such that $xx'=1_A$, which is equivalent to $u(xx')=1_B$, that is to $u(x)\,u(x')=1_B$, or finally to the inversibility of $u(x)$.